# Extract request body information using app.use(req) - NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a NodeJS API and I have the below folder structure. I need to extract the request body information of an API call from the `index.js` itself before passing it to the `stripeController.js`.

- index.js

  - Controllers

    - stripeController.js

I am using the below code segment for data extraction from `index.js` however it returns `undefined` as it cannot identify `req.body` at the time the request goes through the `index.js`.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (req.originalUrl.startsWith('/api/stripeWebHook')) {
    console.log(req.body)
    next();
  }
});

const stripeWebHook = require('./webhook/stripeWebHook')
app.use('/api/stripeWebHook', stripeWebHook)

module.exports = app
```

I can simply extract the body when it reaches the `stripeController.js` using the same attribute.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**req.body**
Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is *undefined***, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser or multer.

```
const app = require('express')()
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const multer = require('multer') // v1.0.5
const upload = multer() // for parsing multipart/form-data

app.use(bodyParser.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

app.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(req.body)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I already have the bodyParser middleware and your solution worked after replacing the location of my code. I just made it to execute just after the bodyParser has been initialized.